# Loading JS and CSS into HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm very new to the HTML markup language.  I have an html table (that I actually generate dynamically using echo statements from a PHP file), and I want to apply some CSS and JS to it so I can have such niceties as row+col mouseover highlighting and fixed table header for scrolling.  I have a few questions,

1. (More of a general inquiry than a specific question) Where could I find good examples of JS or how could I achieve the desired effects that I mentioned above?
2. Where do I place the `<script>` and `<link>` tags to import JS and CSS files so that they take effect on my table?  Up until now, I place the tags in the `<head>` of my HTML body. I've been messing around with various examples I've come across and tried copying the JS code into a file and then telling HTML where to look using the tags but I never seem to be able to have the CSS or JS files execute

Comment: Books. "Eloquent javascript" for example.

Comment: place <link> tags in <header> and <script> tags before closing <body> tag

Answer (score 2):

1. This is a very broad question as there are many ways to do this, but I would recommend checking out examples that are somewhat industry standards nowadays such as Bootstrap. They have classes like table-hover that will do atleast your row highlighting. This is a good basis to build off of.
2. You will want to store the css documents in the head of the page, but your scripts can be loaded in the head of the page or the end of the body. I suspect that the reason your JS documents may not be executing as you would like is because you have code that requires DOM elements (the elements on the page) to be present for event handlers and such to execute upon. You need to wait to execute the code until the DOM elements are done rendering, or atleast those that you are needing to modify.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  In your second bullet, when you say "wait" to execute the JS.  Programmatically what does that look like.  Is it a matter of placing the JS `<script>` code right before `</body>` or is there something else that needs to happen, like within the JS itself?

Comment: It depends on what your JS file looks like but typically you can place it at the end and that will render once the rest of the DOM has been loaded. If you need it at the beginning, you can achieve this using `window.onload` or similar.

Answer (score 2):

1. I know Codecademy's free courses provide decent examples and practices, but other than that I'm not sure.
2. Most of the time CSS will be linked in the `<head>` and is what you'll want to do. The most agreed upon location to link you're JS is at the bottom of the page just before the `</body>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

With your table styles, just browse around looking for some frameworks, these look great.

Where you place your `<script>` tags doesn't matter, they can go in your `<head>` or your `<body>`. Your `<link>` tags can go in your head only though.

Answer (score 1):

For the effects you seek, I'm not convinced you need JS, CSS alone should probably be able to do it in itself - although styling tables isn't something I've done in recent years.

Linking to your css and js file can be done from the `<head>`.

If you have trouble getting it to succeed:

- "inspect" your page in your browser (depends on the browser how to start it)
- look for errors both on the server and/or the console of the browser

I'd expect something to be wrong with the path: if it's a relative path (not starting with http(s):// nor with "/"): it's relative to the path the html is on. If it's an absolute path well then that's from the doc root in the server.